# md-select component loses ng-selected value

Tags: angularjs, safari, angular-material

I work with Angular 1.5.4 & material 1.0.6. Everything of the following example is working fine if I use chrome. But if I use safari no value is preselected.

The template of the component looks like

```
<md-select ng-model="$ctrl.selectedFruit">
      <md-option ng-repeat="fruit in $ctrl.fruits" ng-value="fruit" required
                 ng-selected="$first" >
        {{fruit.name}} {{fruit.weight}}
      </md-option>
</md-select>
```

the component looks like

```
.component('applicantAccount', {
    // @ngInject

    bindings: {
        selectedFruit: "="
    },
    controller: function (accountService) {
        var ctrl = this;
        fruitService.initFruitBefore(function () {
            ctrl.fruits= fruitService.getFruits();
        });
    },
    templateUrl: 'views/templates/selectFruitTemplate.html'
});
```

fruitService:

```
var fruits = [];
var initFruits = function () {
  return $http.get(configuration.apiUrl + "fruits")
    .then(function success(response) {
      fruits =  response.data || []
      return response;
    })
};

var getFruits = function () {
  var filterEx = {type: "fresh"};
  return $filter('filter')(fruits , filterEx);
};

var initFruitBefore = function (callback) {
  if (!areFruitsAvailable()) {
    initFruits().then(callback);
  }
  else{
    callback();
  }
};
var areFruitsAvailable = function () {
  return typeof fruits[0] !== 'undefined'
};
var getFreshFruit = function () {
  var filterEx = {type: "fresh"};
  var filtered = $filter('filter')(fruits, filterEx);

  return filtered[0] || null;
};
```

controller:

```
 fruitService.initFruitBefore(function () {
  ctrl.selectedFruit = accountService.getFreshFruit();
  ctrl.fruits = accountService.getFruits();
});
```

The odd thing(only safari) is, that ctrl.fruits gets initialized before selectedFruit is initialized (outside of the component). If this happens the value was shown for a short term. 
Has anyone an idea whats going on? Why behaves the safari different? 
Thank you & sorry for my bad english

**The Solution**

I added ng-model-options={trackBy:'$value.id'}.

Angular Material:
To determine whether something is selected, ngModelController is looking at whether $scope.selectedUser == (any user in $scope.users);;

Javascript's == operator does not check for deep equality (ie. that all properties on the object are the same), but instead whether the objects are the same object in memory. In this case, we have two instances of identical objects, but they exist in memory as unique entities. Because of this, the select will have no value populated for a selected user.

For futher description look at https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect

Comment: Using your example I created a CodePen and it works in Safari. I hope it can help you. http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/VjBONq?editors=1010#0

Comment: The only difference I see, is that the selectedFruit and the fruits get the data using a promise. 

Is it possible that the order of responses makes the difference?

Comment: Can you edit the question to show the code in fruitService?

Comment: I'm not sure what is causing the problem. Put a bunch of console.logs in your code to check the order of responses.

Comment: the problem is that fruit gets loaded twice.
Once in the Controller and once in the component, the selectedFruit is the first of the Controller. Which have a different objectId like any object of fruits in the component. Why this problem only happens while using Safari is odd.

Comment: Glad you solved it. As note, if you need to do deep equality on objects use `angular.equals` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals

Comment: Thank you for your help.